# How to build a data pipeline through several microservices

Tags: microservices, event-programming

We are building a microservice architecture.

We have one service which imports a set of data (usually, ca. 10MB). Another service should do some analysing and manipulation stuff on these data. A third one should persist the manipulated data into a certain storage.

Unfortunately we don't know what is best practice to send the data from one service to the next.

We thought of following approaches:

1. The import service stores the data into a local storage. Then it publishes an event with the import id. The analysis services catches this message and makes a HTTP GET call to the import service. After that, it stores the manipulated data into its own local storage and starts the same procedure for the persisting service. However, we are not sure if the synchronous GET call is a good idea in an asynchronous event environment.
2. When the import is done, the service sends an event which includes the data as payload/message. So, the analysis service would catch the event and can grap the data directly. Here, we are not sure if it is a good idea to send 10MB data as event load.

What do you think? Is there a best-practice way for such problems?

**Edit** (To make the question more general):

How does an architecture looks like, that consist of several data processing services: Service A does something with data, service B takes A's output, processes it a second time, ..., service N takes the output from service N - 1 and makes final changes. How are these data outputs pushed into the next services?

Comment: Why are you making your microservices so ... micro? Importing, analysing and persisting sounds like three classes within a single microservice to me. By splitting it up, you're making things much harder, for what benefit exactly?

Comment: @RikD It's a very simplified example. The real software is much bigger and the single services do some things more and interact with different actors. The described workflow is just a small excerpt to focus on the problem.

Comment: Perhaps you can find ways to split the 10MB data into chunks that can be processed separately? It's a large amount of data for both suggested solutions. Normally I would go with option 2, but your infrastructure has to allow events of that size.

Comment: Such a service chain with streaming data (streamable assumed, won't work well if every stage in the pipeline wants to see the complete chunk) sounds like a perfect application for Kafka

Comment: @RikD Unfortunately, we cannot split these data. I updated the question with a more general question, maybe that makes the problem a little clearer...

Comment: Take a look at Node-RED.  It might give you some ideas about how to do this sort of pipelines. It might even make yours if your services have compatible interfaces.

Comment: Don't give up on the idea of providing a separate service for the pipeline just yet - if the other services have additional things to do, you could potentially just send messages from the processing pipeline service to the other services - just enough to enable them to do their work (the bits that aren't *directly* related to the core processing logic), instead of sending your data through several network hops. In other words, it's possible that you have distributed responsibilities across services in a way that makes things harder for you (coupling, performance hits, low cohesion).

Comment: @FilipMilovanović I am not quite sure if I fully understood what you mean with "pipeline service". May I ask you to explain this in more detail?

Comment: I just mean the single dedicated microservice that would actually process the data, the same thing other people have been suggesting in the comments and answers - except that you could potentially send messages to these other services (since you've said they have extra tings to do).

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments, there might well be room to consolidate this pipeline into a single service ([Enterprise Integration Patterns](https://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/) being the most common way to think about designing these kinds of pipelines).

Assuming that this is not what you are looking for or will not work, you're really doing a form of [flow based programming](https://jpaulm.github.io/fbp/index.html). In this sort of approach to data pipelines, each component/microservices is a black box, opaque to each of the others and handles some specific piece of the workflow. The "pipe" part of the pipeline is usually some sort of messaging system (RabbitMQ, ActiveMQ, Kafka, Event Hubs, ServiceBus, etc.). This allows service A to do work and queue up transformed work for service B.

[image]

As mentioned in some of the flow-based programming links, this would technically be more flow-based programming (FBP) inspired, but you could take this approach and go all the way if you wanted to.

Comment: So, you are recommending the second approach, using the event messages for sending all the data throughout the microservices?

Comment: That's probably what I would do, yes, if I had decided to absolutely keep the processes as separate microservices / containers.